# Air-conditioned cafe in Kampot, Cambodia?

Tags: cambodia, food-and-drink

Sometimes when travelling in hot humind places you want a couple of hours respite in a nice spot with air conditioning to work out your plans, keep in touch on the Internet, etc.

Kampot is well established on the tourist map and expat maps, which usually makes such places pretty easy to find. But today all the coffee shops I could find had open doors despite the heat so I just spent all afternoon sweating.

**Is there a cafe that's cooled inside that I didn't find?** In the past I've asked some questions looking for places with Wi-Fi and electricty - here that's the easy part - almost everybody has it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google search revealed [this tripadvisor review mentioning amazing brownies and air-conditioning](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g608455-d2431658-r226143755-Sisters_II_Bakery_Cafe-Kampot_Kampot_Province.html), dating September 2014:

> If you get the opportunity, call in for a coffee and a brownie in this air conditioned coffee shop. The cakes are all made on site, a large variety, but it would be hard to go past the brownie. Free wifi too.

Sounds like a perfect combination to me. The mentioned place should be [here, according to google maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Sisters+II/@10.607262,104.181059,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x310836887de87e27:0xeb26998aebf78bcf).

As a tip and trick I would suggest to try hotel/hostel bars. It would make sense to assume that the bar inside an air-conditioned establishment will also be air-conditioned. And often you don't need to be a hotel guest to use these facilities.

Comment: All of the hostel bars seem to be open air too. I guess they just have aircon in some of the rooms. I think I read about SistersII in Wikivoyage so I'll check it out tomorrow! If it's near the 2000 roundabout that's actually one of the spots I saw but didn't wander up to yet.

Comment: I was going to reply from this cafe yesterday, but due to a wedding party in the street outside, it and adjoining businesses were closed. This seems to be normal in Cambodia (-: